# Can't run my application due to Dalvik format failure (Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dalvik

In the console it says:

Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/kobjects/base64/Base64;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/kobjects/base64/Base64;

Tried to build automatically and clean the project and import it again. Still won't work.
Help would be very appreciated. :)

Comment: Uncheck the Automatic build option and delete the generated file and bin folder clean the project, Rebuild project by right click on project in eclipse and run again.

Comment: I've done that Sadiq but thanks... still won't work... I imported my project on android studio once then returned to eclipse if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Take the Backup of all jar and lib folder

Now, follow these steps.

Remove all jar files except android-support-v4.jar from the 'Android Dependencies' folder under Project Explorer in Eclipse.

Similarly remove all Jar files except android-support-v4.jar from the  libs folder under Project Explorer in Eclipse.

Now Right click on your project-> Select Properties-> Select Java Build Path-> Select Add External JARs. Add all the necessary jar files (just make sure you add a particular jar file only once).

Finally clean the project and build it. Now apply the same sequence of steps to the pro version. That should do it.

If there would be any import error then you just have to press ctrl+shift+O